# How to add testInstrumentation environment variable for firebase testlab?

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, android-testing, firebase-test-lab

If i am going to run espresso test locally and pass enviroment variable
i can do this by
adding

```
defaultConfig {
 testInstrumentationRunnerArgument 'USERNAME' 'David'
}
```

in **build.gradle file**

then i can call this variable by

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments().getString("USERNAME")
```

but when i run this on firebase testlab 
instrumentationrunner argument are not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported in Test Lab.

If you really need to do this, there's a workaround by overriding the test runner and using the test runner "environment variables" to pass in those key-value pairs.

Override the test runner:

```
public class MyTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

    public static String USERNAME;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
        super.onCreate(arguments);

        USERNAME = arguments.getString("USERNAME");
    }
}
```

Use `MyTestRunner` in your `build.gradle` file:

```
defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.myapp.MyTestRunner"
}
```

Start your test run in Firebase using the `gcloud` command-line app. This is where you pass in your arguments:

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
    --type instrumentation \
    --app debug/app-debug.apk \
    --test androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk \
    --environment-variables "USERNAME=david" \
    --device model=walleye,version=28
```